# Stretch checkbox the whole width of a parent combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a problem with the combobox below and its source items:

When I expand the combobox, the checkbox doesn't stretch the whole width of the combobox. This means that if I click outside a checkbox in the expanded the combobox, the text property of the combobox will be evaluted to the String() property of the selected item (Which is the Location model (Datacontext)).

I think the easiest way to stretch the checkbox the whole width of the combobox. I have not been successful in doing that.

**Is there a way to stretch the width of the checkbox the whole length of the combobox using xaml only?**

Thanks SO!

```
  <DataTemplate>
     <ComboBox Text ="{Binding LocationNames}" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"> 
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property of the `ComboBoxItem` container to `Stretch`:

```
<ComboBox Text ="{Binding LocationNames}" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```