# Alignment of DataTemplated Items in Combobox + passing Current item to command

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, alignment, datatemplate

How to align to the right X buttons in the WPF Combobox?
What I got is this:
[image]

**Xaml:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}" >

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EntityName, Mode=OneWay}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteEntityCommand, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">

                    <Image Source="..\Resources\DeleteIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

`Entities` is an `ObservableCollection` of some `Entity` class.
Do I have to use something else instead of `Grid`?

**One more question:**
if user clicked on the X button of some item then it has to be passed to `DeleteEntityCommand` (using `CommandParameter` maybe). How to do it? `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` is still AAAAAA, not HHHH (see the pic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch checkbox the whole width of a parent combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425756/stretch-checkbox-the-whole-width-of-a-parent-combobox)

Comment: Setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce it. With your code I have buttons on the right side of drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that your Grid in the Template isnt stretched across the available space. According to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49426122/9669202) it can be achieved with

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        //etc.
```

Note: If you dont define the width of your Button it will be stretched across the remaining space. I Suggest to add a Columndefinition with Width=Auto and add the Button there (Grid.Column=2).

**Edit**

The additionaly column is meant to be a filler like this (left) because your Buttons may stretch themself across the available space (right).

[image] [image]

**Second Question**

You can set the Commandparameter of a Command and if im not mistaken, the Item itself can be passed with {Binding}.

```
<Button Command={Binding ...} Commandparameter={Binding}/>
```

And the ICommand implementation must be extended/overloaded to accept Parameter.

Comment: Second question is answered, I confirm, thanks a lot. But approach with `HorizontalContentAlignment` doesn't work for me.
Can you elaborate on adding one more column? I didn't get it..
1st column is text, 3rd is button, what is in the 2nd column?

Comment: Nothing, this is supposed to be a filler for the variable, empty space between the Button and the Text (see Edit). And for answering your first question: what is the Size of your ComboBox and the Grid inside the Datatemplate? What happens if you set the width of the Grid manually?

Comment: my problem was that the sizes of `GridColumns` were set to `Auto`. After I set it to fixed values the issue is gone.